# Chrome - Resizing Window for Web Responsiveness Testing

Tags: google-chrome, display

I'm using Google Chrome 33 on Windows XP, both at work and home. At home I can resize the the window and see the responsive web pages working without releasing the mouse. But at work I have to release the mouse to see the result and the pages change.

In both places I have set my Gmail account up, so everything is synchronized. I have tried some extensions, but I haven't found a solution.

What causes could result in this difference between my Chrome installations? Is it Chrome or Windows XP configuration? It is much more comfortable to see the results without needing to release the mouse.

Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards, Pablo

Comment: I know we geeks can be fussy about the little things, but does this really matter that much? Or are you more interested as a technical exercise as to why Chrome might respond differently?

Comment: It is not life/death question, that's clear. But it is something that bothers me and something that I don't understand. I'm more inclined to your second question because I may be have something set up differently that is wrong